# Fastest way to write files to SharePoint document library

Tags: performance

What is the fastest way to write files to a SharePoint document library server-side, considering we only need to write lots of files (byte[]s) and we do not need to consider metadata or other stuff (only files)?

For example:

```
SPFileCollection files = library.RootFolder.Files;
foreach (LargeFile largeFile in MyFiles)
{
  SPFile file = files.Add(largeFile.FileName, largeFile.Bytes);
}
```

Are there faster ways?

Or with metadata:

```
SPFileCollection files = library.RootFolder.Files;
foreach (LargeFile largeFile in MyFiles)
{
  SPFile file = files.Add(largeFile.FileName, largeFile.Bytes);
  SPListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields;
  item["Title"] = "Test";
  item.Update();
}
```

(a related question might be if SharePoint converts CSOM batches to this kind of code first)

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use WebClient and UploadFile method, see example below:

```
        public static void UploadToSP(string[] files, string serverPath)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.Write("Upload file: {0}", file);

                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
                Uri uri = new Uri(serverPath + fileName);
                wc.UploadFile(uri, "PUT", file);

                Console.WriteLine(" - Uploaded");
            }
        }
```

And how to use:

```
var serverPath      = "http://dev2/sites/test01/Shared Documents/Folder1/";
var uploadDirectory = @"C:\temp\upload";

UploadToSP(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(uploadDirectory), serverPath);
```

Also you can change this example and upload files asynchronously.

P.S.: Don't forget about filename limitations described [on msdn](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231/en-us)